# How to extract href with ampersand using Gatling?

Tags: html, gatling

When I need to follow a link on a page in a Gatling stresstest, there is a problem if the URL contains ampersands. Presumably because Gatling is interpreting it as an entity. How can one get around that?

Example:

Say you first receive a webpage containing

```
<a href="go?to=foobar&index=null" title="Choice 1">
```

Now if I try to follow this link with

```
exec(
  http("page with link")
  .get("/page1")
  .check(css("""a[title='Choice 1']""", "href").saveAs("url"))
)
.exec(
  http("follow link")
  .get("${url}")
)
```

then the URL being used for the second request is `go?to=foobar%E2%88%88dex=null`

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Jodd](http://jodd.org/) (the html parser + css selector implementation we use) [issue](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/issues/245).

It has already been fixed in sources, and should be released soon.
Then, force dependency version in Gatling.

Comment: Editing answer as this is a duplicate of another issue that as already been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is "correct" to have unescaped ampersands in HTML attributes. But some websites have them and browsers handle it. Some websites even have both `&` and `&amp;` in the same attribute. But as of version 2.1.7 Gatling's CSS selector cannot handle plain (unescaped) ampersands.

In case others have the same problem, here is a dirty hack:

```
regex("""href="([^"]+)".* title="Choice 1">""")
.transform(raw => raw.replace("&amp;", "&"))
```

Of course you should never use a regex on HTML (or XML). In this case never means "until it works with CSS selectors".